# Oracle APEX interactive report: pivot link to page

Tags: pivot, oracle-apex

is it possible to put a link, even with a workaround, in the pivots made with the interactive report?
Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25QUR.png)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with a: minimal example of a pivot you are using in an interactive report; a description of the logic you want to use; **YOUR** attempts at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt; and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is.

For the rows it is very easy: just make the column a link column - it will still be a link even if the report is in pivot view.

If you need to make the data fields clickable, you will have to add a link with jquery. Just make a dynamic action that runs after refresh of the report and let it do something like this:

```
$("#Buchungen .u-tR").attr("onClick",("drilldown('f?p=147:1:&APP_SESSION.:IRBuchungen_',this.headers)"));
```

"Buchungen" is the static id of my report.

drilldown is a javascript funktion on page level that uses row and column headers to compose a link for a detail view:

```
function drilldown(p_link, p_headers)
{
  var a_headers = p_headers.split(" ");
  // sind auch 3 headers dabei (i.e. ist es pivot))
  if (a_headers.length >= 3) {
 // suche P header, suche ersten R header

 var v_Pheader = document.getElementById(a_headers[0]).innerText;
 var v_Rheader = document.getElementById(a_headers[2]).innerHTML;
 
 // filter for column P and row R , zoom in.
 // Zoom-in is link to saved detail report with filters
 //
 // link looks like this: f?p=app:page:&SESSION.:IRstaticregion_XXX::RIR:IR_row,IR_col
 //
 //replace: app page staticregion row col

 // saved report alias must be declared manually
 // frist find the selectted id
 var v_selected_report_id = $("#Buchungen_saved_reports").find(":selected").val();
 var v_selected_report_alias = 'unknown';
 var v_filters;
 
 //then enter the alias (you must enter the right values) 
 if (v_selected_report_id == '203369431355456312') {v_selected_report_alias = 2039784; v_filters = 'IR_ACCOUNTNAME,IR_MONAT'}; //Pers/Monat -> Proj/Tag
 //if (v_selected_report_id == '203975724318962475') {v_selected_report_alias = 2039758; v_filters = 'IR_ACCOUNTNAME,IR_MONAT'}; //Pers/Tag -> ?
 //if (v_selected_report_id == '203978346734023135') {v_selected_report_alias = 2039784; v_filters = 'IR_ACCOUNTNAME,IR_MONAT'}; //Proj/Tag --?
 if (v_selected_report_id == '203981494105027754') {v_selected_report_alias = 2039758; v_filters = 'IR_PROJEKTNAME,IR_MONAT'}; //Proj/Monat --> Pers/Tag
 
 //redirect: window.location.replace
 //better simulate a click
 if (v_selected_report_alias != 'unknown') 
    { window.location.href = p_link+v_selected_report_alias+'::RIR:'+v_filters+':'+v_Rheader+','+v_Pheader;
};
};  
};
```

The line with window.location.href does the redirect to another page.

I hope, this helps.
Michael